# constexpr and lambda, is it possible

Tags: c++, constexpr

Is there any issue with this code ? It make my msvc crash at this line.
However with gcc it works well

`constexpr auto d = for_each_tuple(t, [](auto i) {return 2.0 * i;});`

However I do not have problem when I use it without constexpr.

Here is the full code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<typename Function, typename ...types, std::size_t ...Is>
constexpr double for_each_impl(std::tuple<types...> t, Function f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    double r{0.0};

    auto l = [&r, &f](auto t) {
        r += f(t);
    };

    (l(std::get<Is>(t)), ...);

    return r;
}

template<typename Function, typename ...types>
constexpr double for_each_tuple(std::tuple<types...> t, Function f) {
    using Indices = std::index_sequence_for<types...>;
    return for_each_impl(t, f, Indices{});
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::tuple<int, double, unsigned int> t{1, 2.0, 3u};

    constexpr auto d = for_each_tuple(t, [](auto i) {return 2.0 * i;});

    static_assert(d == 12.0, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of MSVC do you use? In this [online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/CPNCRp) it cannot even compile.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017 15.5. I use the option /std:c++latest

Comment: And you can test the code in clang / gcc, you will not have any error and it works just fine.

In MSVC, I do not get any error, just MSVC crash

Comment: Did you file a bug report for MSVC?

Comment: No, I wanted to know if the code is correct or not. If not I will do so.